# Custom nested headers for Django-Tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'd like to have Django-Tables2 to produce headers like these ones shown in the image bellow:[[image: custom composed header [1]]

Any hint how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward approach for this in django-tables2. For a single usecase, I would say using a custom template based on [django_tables2/table.html](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html) would be the way to go.

If you really want to implement this in a flexible way, here are some thoughts:

1. put a 'group' attribute on each column, defaulting to `None`.
2. Amend the template to render columns with `group=None` with `rowspan="2"`.
3. Render the group names with the appropriate `colspan` (I think some method on the bound column should be able to infer this from its table member)
4. Render the remaining columns headers in the next header row.

This might be hard to monkey patch into django-tables2 and not worth the effort. If you decide to take that route and have a nice implementation, make sure to open a pull request on the django-tables2 github repo so we can consider adding it to the core.